# How to add QMenus or Qactions on a Widget like QlistWidget area as a list item?

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any way to add QActions as a list item on QListWidget?
I want to make a customization window which will show list of actions on a widget for *move up*, *move down*, *Rename* and other options. I'd like to display it on the widget same as it appears as a context menu.

I tried adding it as a list item with icon and text, but the look it not very good:

i) list items with blank icon are not aligning properly, even after adding a blank icon of size 16*16 is not taking up any space and text with icons & w/o icon are not aligning.

ii) I'm unable to add right-pointing black triangle at the right most, in-case of sub-menus cause somehow unicode character for this is not getting displayed on my Linux machine.
That's why I want to add QActions as it are getting popped at original place.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The typical way to architect such things is to implement a viewmodel that adapts a "list" of actions to something that can be manipulated by a human. You then display such viewmodel in a `QListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have a suggestion : do not try to make fancy widgets like this, users will not find it intuitive

You should find another way to implement this.

Imo, something like a `QToolButton` with a `QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup` popup mode will do the trick. This way, you can embed menu and sub-menus in a widget, using `QToolButton::setMenu()`.